# Azure self-hosted build agent: ##[error]Version spec 3.10 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I followed the Microsoft guidance on installing a self-hosted build agent for Windows on my local machine. The agent is running and responsive and can successfully execute all task steps preceding point of failure.

The failing task is `UsePythonVersion@0` task which is defined as such below:

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.10'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
```

The error raised when build is executed:

> ##[error]Version spec 3.10 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.

I [configured the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops) to run this task as per the steps detailed in the URL. This can be seen in the provided screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I added [user-defined capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities) as per Microsoft guidance which were not picked automatically due to being environment variables

[image]

The Python environment target is a virtual one and was installed in place. The Python environment was not on the path so I added it and restarted the **Azure Pipelines Agent** service. *I don't think it needs to be on the path, but I might be incorrect*.

Another user had a GitHub issue open and the recommendation was to not specify the Python subversion. I tried this and set `versionSpec: '3'`, this did not resolve the error and the message did not change.

I tried restarting the **Azure Pipelines Agent** service after making changes to the `tools_` directory.

Also note that I have not overridden `$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/`.

I referenced [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936103/install-python-to-self-hosted-windows-build-agent) and tried moving files from the script directory one level up. This did not resolve my issue. I also reinstalled python precompiled into this directory as per the recommendation. That did not resolve the problem either.

I also reinstalled Python 3.10 for all users precompiled **C:\Program Files\Python310** and updated the path. I restarted the service and was able to see the new location added to the path in the agent capabilities. I ran the CI pipe again and the same error was returned.

I have removed the step for now and added a user capability to the agent which references the Python installation that I want to use. It seems to be using that installation. This is not satisfactory though.

I don't know what I have missed.